# Create custom json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Json object coming from my api as:

```
{
    "user1": ["report_dev", "report_test"],
    "user2": ["output1", "output2", "output3", "output4"]
}
```

I want to convert this to this format:

```
[{ name: 'user1' }, { name: 'user2' }];
```

This must be simple enough but not sure about this. Do I have to loop through json and create custom one.

I tried with below code but this is not giving my expected result:

```
var array =[];
for (i in array1)
{
    //array1 holds the json object
    array.push('name', array1[i]]);
}
```

Thanks for looking into.

Updated:

```
  details1:
     user1: (2) ["report_dev", "report_test"]
     user2: (4) ["output1", "output2", "output3", "output4"]

  details2:
     user1: (2) ["report_dev", "report_test"]
     user2: (4) ["output1", "output2", "output3", "output4"]
```

Comment: I think you're after something like this: `Object.keys(array1).map(name => ({name}));`, but can make your input a little clearer?

Comment: I have updated my question.does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach currently isn't working as you're trying to push two values into your array as separate items/elements. You want to [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Syntax) an object in your desired format that you've included in your output array:

```
var array = [];
for (var i in array1) { // array1 holds the object (it is NOT an array)
    array.push({"name": i, "data": array1[i]});
}
```

Alternatively, you could get an array of key-value pairs `keys` from your object using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then map (using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) that to its own object:

```
var array = Object.entries(array1).map(([name, data]) => ({name, data}));
```

**EDIT**

As per your edit, you'll need to iterate over your outer `details` object keys. This can be done by using `Object.entries` again, and re-mapping each `detail` key to point to your re-mapped inner object like so:

```js
const obj = {
  "details1": {
    "user1": ["report_dev", "report_test"],
    "user2": ["output1", "output2", "output3", "output4"]
  },

  "details2": {
    "user1": ["report_dev", "report_test"],
    "user2": ["output1", "output2", "output3", "output4"]
  }
}

const res = Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(obj).map(([det, obj]) => ({
   [det]: Object.entries(obj).map(([name, data]) => ({name, data}))
})));

console.log(res);
```

This can also be done using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) by mappying to an array of `[key, value]` pairs:

```js
const obj = {
  "details1": {
    "user1": ["report_dev", "report_test"],
    "user2": ["output1", "output2", "output3", "output4"]
  },

  "details2": {
    "user1": ["report_dev", "report_test"],
    "user2": ["output1", "output2", "output3", "output4"]
  }
}

const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(
  ([det, obj]) => [det, Object.entries(obj).map(([name, data]) => ({name, data}))]
));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. Sorry for this but one of my data is returning parent child json as updated above.

Comment: what is your desired output now? Can you update the question again please

Comment: Everything remains same, I just want to update my original json object with "name": "user1" and "name": "user2" rest of json remains same as it is

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate into the json you received from the API as Nick Parsons proposes:

```js
const fetchedData = {"user1":["report_dev", "report_test"], "user2": ["output1", "output2", "output3", "output4"]}

const result = Object.keys(fetchedData).map((key) => {
   return {
       name: key,
       data: fetchedData[key],
   }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is fine but with this I dont get my data associated with user1 and user2 ie ["report_dev", "report_test"] and ["output1", "output2", "output3", "output4"] .Sorry I dint mention this in my post

Comment: @user1563677 take a look at your desired output. It doesn't include those arrays :/

Comment: Okay, updated, but next time specify better what do you want

Comment: Sorry about this but I now realize I am getting complex json back as mentuioned in my updated post above.
I wrote too soon, should have analysed my json first.
Would appreciate if this can be looked into. Will certainly post full code going further